# Converting numpy array (or python list) to integer

Tags: python, numpy, binary, integer

**I THINK BELOW QUESTION IS NOT POSSIBLE TO CALCULATE, SIMPLY BECAUSE 2^250 to BIG TO CALCULATE.**

---

I have a numpy array, which has a shape of `(1000,250)` with binary values and I want to convert the whole array to integer values;

```
>>>in_[0]
array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int64)


>>>in_.shape
(1000, 250)
```

What is expected:

```
>>>out
array([<big-value>], [<big-value>], [<big-value>], ...)
# array of size (1000,1)
```

Last element of the `in_[0]` is the `2^0*element_value`:

```
...1, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
# ... + 2^3*1 + 2^2*1 + 2^1*0 + 2^0*1]
```

Comment: can you clarify which power of 2 is coded by each 1?

Comment: @mozway - I think packbits won't work in this case, since my individual arrays are size 250 instead of 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`packbits`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.packbits.html):

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1])

out = np.packbits(np.pad(a, (8-len(a), 0)))

# or
out = np.packbits(a[::-1], bitorder='little')
```

Output: `array([7], dtype=uint8)`

Or manually performing the computation with powers of 2:

```
out = ((2**np.arange(len(a)))*a[::-1]).sum()
```

Output: `7`

###### using pure python:

```
a = in_[0]
out = sum(2**i for i, x in enumerate(a[::-1]) if x)
```

Output with the updated example:

```
1351989656832611222849160586388676483515836127975177046080313769140774859213
```

For the whole array, which should be reasonably fast for (1000, 256):

```
out = [sum(2**i for i, x in enumerate(a[::-1]) if x) for a in in_]
```

Comment: it is not working as expected with my data, I updated the question could you check again?

Comment: @oakca `packbits` is indeed limited to inputs of size 8, the manual computation should work, provided the computation is doable. Even if you use `uint64` and the power of 2 approach, the maximum number that can be computed by numpy (`np.iinfo(np.uint64).max`) is far below yours (up to `2**251`). I updated the answer with a solution in pure python.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input, this is 1 possible way to do it:

```
 # Import numpy
import numpy as np

# Regenerate your input
in_ = np.round(np.random.rand(1000*250)).reshape(1000,250).astype(int)

# Create lambda function to transform array of bin into integer
f_bin = lambda x: int("0b" + "".join([str(num) for num in x ]),2)

# apply lambda function to input, result is a numpy array (1000,)
# we reshape to (1000,1) for your desired output
out_ = np.apply_along_axis(f_bin, 1, in_).reshape(1000,1)
```

Your result is the numpy array out_

Answer (score -1):

You could use the int+base method, which goes as following for your code:

```
int(x = yourarray,base = 10).
```